# Finding the elements with no children

Tags: jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

My goal: Change background of element when hovering element.

The problem: I have a `*` selector which adds `mouseover/mouseout` effect to all elements.
However, I only need to change background of the deepest element I hover, i.e the element with no children.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="skinke" niveau="1">
        <img niveau="2" class="hest" id="dyr" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Patern_test.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="bil hest" niveau="1">
        <p niveau="2">Asdnjkewr</p>
    </div>
    <ul niveau="1">
        <li class="aefae" niveau="2">
            <p id="bold" niveau="3">1. sdfsdf</p>
        </li>
        <li niveau="2">
            <p id="to" niveau="3">fiweorew</p> <---- I want only the <p> tag to change background
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="re">werwerw</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p>wreer</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

To clarify, I've added a comment in the above to help understanding.

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to target everything for parsing. Create a list of the elements you need the function attached to.  `$('.one-thing, .another .thing, .a > p')...`

Comment: How about targeting elements with no children (`:empty`)? http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

Comment: @isherwood Problem is, I want this to be a generalization. I want to use in the allow the element which represents the value he wants.

Comment: @GriffeyDog You may be right! I was wrong in my first comment.

Comment: @GriffeyDog You're right! That is the correct answer.

Comment: How do you determine the `deepest` element?

Comment: @user3558931 the element with no children.

Comment: I got it. So if I am hovering in `<ul nivieau="1">...` -- by the way niveau is not a standard attribute -- and not necessarily in any of it's children, there will be several deepest elements, right?

Comment: @mhermann i've edited the question with the info from your comments. Please update it if i missed something. hope the answer helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of event delegation and bind the click handler to the `document` instead of binding a handler to each and every elements. (*this also has the added advantage of working with dynamically added elements.*)

The [:empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) selector mentioned in comments will not work with elements such as `<h1>`, `<p>` etc due to the `textNodes`. You can make use of the use the [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method instead to check for actual child elements as follows:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','*',function(){
 if(!$(this).children().length)
   $(this).addClass('highlight');
});
$(document).on('mouseleave','*',function(){
 if($(this).hasClass('highlight'))
   $(this).removeClass('highlight');
});
```

CSS

```
.highlight{
  background-color:dodgerblue;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Cb9G/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this:

```
$(elementBeingHovered).hover(function() {
    $(elementToChange).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

Or if you're hovering the same element you want to change:

```
#to:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I may want to use hover instead of mouseover. However, I don't know the element being hovered.

Comment: The above does use hover? If you want only one element to change when EVERY other element is hovered you can still use the jQuery above, just use $("*") as the selector; although, like other people have said, it's generally not good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure I captured you goal and intent fully but the following might be helpful, especially in determining the deepest element(s) of any hovered element.

The method `.contents()` returns all children including `textNodes` (nodeType=3). The while loop stops when there're only textnode children.

```
$(function() {
    $('*').hover(function() {
        var that = $(this);
        while( that.contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 1; }).length > 0 ) {
            that = that.contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 1; });
        };
        that.css('backgroundColor', 'red');
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/X4m9u/)

I hope this helps you reach your goal.